# Why can't save the parsed result into localstorage automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, location, local-storage

The parsed anchor elements can be saved in localstorage by two steps.
step1
To open `https://www.yahoo.com/` in chrome
step2
To run the code in `inspect--console`.

```
var as=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var result='';
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
    result +=as[i]+"  ";
 }
localStorage.setItem("parse_anchor", result);
```

[image]

To open localstorage, key is `parse_anchor` and value is `result`(a long string) can be seen.

[image]

Now to write the following code and save it as  `parse_anchor.html`.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href="https://www.yahoo.com/";
var as=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var result='';
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
     result +=as[i]+"  ";
 }
localStorage.setItem("parse_anchor", result);
</script>
</html>
```

No key-value pair can be seen in chrome's localstorage when to open the file `parse_anchor.html` with chrome.

Comment: Actually your key is `parse_anchor` and `result` is your value; if you want to store object in localStorage you might want to checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to save an array of DOM Object's into localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

The key and value types are `[DOMString][1]` , but you're trying to save an `object` | `array`.

I don't know what you're trying to store on `localStorage`, but this is a snippet that actually works.

**EDIT :**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var as=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var result='';
    for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
         result +=as[i]+"  ";
     }
    localStorage.setItem("parse_anchor", JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

Comment: My problem is that  when to save the code as parse_anchor.html,and to open the file `parse_anchor.html` ,no parsed anchor elements  saved in localstorage.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(result));` doesn't matter.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("parse_anchor", result);` has   such the same effect  as `localStorage.setItem("parse_anchor", JSON.stringify(result));`.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature missed that out completelly. Well the easiest way in web API without jQuery and stuff is to use the onload event of window.